# Stop showing blank page on cancelled login - Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have searched for answers with no luck on my problem and thus I hope you can provide me with some help.

My company is using `Ember.js`, which I have very little knowledge of, and one of our current user stories is to make it possible to show the user something else than a blank page on cancelled login prompt. I have tried making cancel actions etc in the ex-button-Component and login-controller (sorry but cannot show that code), but with no visible change.

The solution could either be a redirection to a page ("you pressed cancel!"), some sort of alert ("ey, you cancelled!") or simply go back to the login prompt.

I provide you with the code for the login template below:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">{{t 'logon.title' logonIdBinding="logonId"}}</h2>
    {{#if logonFailed}}
        {{show-alert error=true message=errorMessage}}
    {{/if}}
    {{input type="text" value=logonId placeholder=(t "logon.username") class="form-control"}}
    {{input type="password" value=password placeholder=(t "logon.password") class="form-control"}}

    {{ex-button icon="fa fa-upload" type="submit" _type="primary" clicked="logon" isLoading=isLoading text=(t 'button.login')}}
</form>
```

Comment: When the form submits, and youre handling the logic to see if the user is logged in, if logon fails use `transitionTo()` to redirect to another route.

Comment: "sorry but cannot show that code" we can't really help if we don't know what you're doing and how it is you're doing it, try to extract the code or at least replicate the problem

Comment: Craicerjack, thank you! Will give it another try with your suggested approach.

Comment: Kitler, actually you should be able to provide help since this is not a case-specific problem, but a general one. You could simple rephrase everything, without any code, to "In Ember,js, how do I direct to another page (or go back to original one) when login is cancelled". FYI, tried using the controller and route "connected" to this handlebar to do some kind of "onCancel" event (lacking better words to describe this), similarly to onClick. However, my attempt was not fruitful.